# Functions parameters using macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I wanted to know if it was contraindicated to define functions parameters using a macro, knowing they *could* be variable. Does it break a coding convention ?

example:

```
#ifdef PREVIOUSLY_DEFINED_MACRO
#   define PARAMETERS int a, long b
#else
#   define PARAMETERS int a
#endif

void my_func(PARAMETERS)
{
   ...
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: This is obfuscating the code, which is not a good thing.

Comment: It's valid, but watch out for accidental ABI breaks. Signatures in public library headers should match the signature of the implementation.

Comment: @PSkocik they will.

Comment: Don't do this, it's bad practice. It's not because you _can_ do something in C that you _should_ do it.

Comment: That's the reason why I was asking if it breaks a convention.

Comment: That said, the problem is in the end of what I typed: "knowing it **could** be variable". I should have maybe put it in bold.

Comment: *"knowing they could be variable"* - But they're *not "variable". The function declaration generated from this is dependent on `PREVIOUSLY_DEFINED_MACRO` entirely, a preprocessor macro. After the preprocess phase `my_func` s formal declaration is chiseled; before then it doesn't even exist. If you want runtime variadic arguments there are ways to do it, but this isn't it. Further, even the compile-time usefulness of this is highly suspect, as it does you little good to vary `a` vs. `a,b` in an argument list without the function below needing to be just as aware. More preprocessed hackery.

Comment: you should go all the way and add function mane as we.ll to the macro `if(myfunc1) then myfunc2;else myfunc3;`

Comment: I maybe didn't explain it right. When I say "variable", it can be, I don't know, platform dependent, or compiler dependent. Let's say instead of "MY_PREVIOUSLY_DEFINED_MACRO" I placed "_MCS_VER". Then the arguments would depend on the compiler. Also, thanks for your answers, I now know it's a bad coding style, but valid.

Comment: Normally you'd just write two entirely separate versions of the function, in separate `#ifdef` blocks.  Or if there is a lot of overlap, then just use `#ifdef` to conditionally compile the correct version.  What's confusing is to pull it out into the `PARAMETERS` macro.

Answer (score 0):

The code is completely valid but, it's not a good coding practice.

Let's assume the following code snippet:

```
#ifdef PREV_DEFINED
    #define ARGS int x, int y
#else
    #define ARGS int x
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

// #define PREV_DEFINED
int func(ARGS) {
    // In this context, only 'x' is available
    // set by the macro
    return (x + y); // ERROR, 'y' is undefined

    // You need to make a different code, specifically for
    // #ifdef PREV_DEFINED  and  #else
}
```

To solve this, you need to make two or more different functions within those `#ifdef` and `#endif` flags whose usage is controlled by the `PREV_DEFINED` macro that depends on how many parameters could be variadic. Eventually, this will make the code look worse.